# infinite image ticker animation stutter

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, animation

I'm using jQuery's animate to create an infinite image ticker - in principle this works well but the animation stutters. After looking (a lot) online at various alternatives such as Velocity and trying these alternatives out I just cannot get a smooth ticker to work.  I think the problem is caused by jQuery itself not making good use of the GPU but I'm not sure how to solve this problem.

The HTML looks like this:

```js
var img;

function imgScroll() {
  img = $(".retailer-scroller .gallery-row img").first();
  var newspeed = 80000 / (40 - (Math.sqrt(img.width()) * 1.65));
  img.animate({
    width: 0,
    padding: 0
  }, newspeed, 'linear', function() {
    img.removeAttr("style");
    img.remove();
    $(".retailer-scroller .gallery-row").append(img);
    imgScroll();
  });
}
$(document).ready(function() {
  imgScroll();
});
```

```css
.retailer-scroller {
  width: 100%;
  height: 70px;
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
  margin: 10px 0;
}
.retailer-scroller .gallery-row {
  min-width: 2000px;
  height: 65px;
  position: absolute;
  left: -500px;
  white-space: nowrap;
  padding: 0;
}
.retailer-scroller .gallery-row img {
  display: inline-block;
}
.img-responsive {
  height: auto;
  max-width: 100%;
}
.retailer-scroller img {
  filter: grayscale(100%);
  max-height: 65px;
  opacity: 0.75;
  padding-left: 50px;
  width: auto;
}
.retailer-scroller img:hover {
  filter: none;
  opacity: 1;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="retailer-scroller">
  <div class="row gallery-row">
    <img alt="boots" class="img-responsive" src="//s3.amazonaws.com/studio4-demofiles/nkg/boots.png">
    <img alt="specsavers" class="img-responsive" src="//s3.amazonaws.com/studio4-demofiles/nkg/specsavers.png">
    <img alt="RSMcCollLogo" class="img-responsive" src="//s3.amazonaws.com/studio4-demofiles/nkg/RSMcCollLogo.jpg">
    <img alt="kirkgate-barbers" class="img-responsive" src="//s3.amazonaws.com/studio4-demofiles/nkg/kirkgate-barbers1.jpg">
    <img alt="semichem-red" class="img-responsive" src="//s3.amazonaws.com/studio4-demofiles/nkg/semichem-red.jpg">
    <img alt="Poundland-Logo" class="img-responsive" src="//s3.amazonaws.com/studio4-demofiles/nkg/Poundland-Logo.jpg">
    <img alt="shoezone" class="img-responsive" src="//s3.amazonaws.com/studio4-demofiles/nkg/shoezone.png">
    <img alt="lidl" class="img-responsive" src="//s3.amazonaws.com/studio4-demofiles/nkg/lidl.png">
    <img alt="HandT_pawn" class="img-responsive" src="//s3.amazonaws.com/studio4-demofiles/nkg/HandT_pawn-e1427199428773.jpg">
    <img alt="store21logo2" class="img-responsive" src="//s3.amazonaws.com/studio4-demofiles/nkg/store21logo2-e1427200645809.jpg">
    <img alt="Peacocks-Logo" class="img-responsive" src="//s3.amazonaws.com/studio4-demofiles/nkg/Peacocks-Logo.jpg">
    <img alt="optical express" class="img-responsive" src="//s3.amazonaws.com/studio4-demofiles/nkg/optical-express.png">
    <img alt="farmfoods" class="img-responsive" src="//s3.amazonaws.com/studio4-demofiles/nkg/farmfoods.png">
    <img alt="bankofscotland" class="img-responsive" src="//s3.amazonaws.com/studio4-demofiles/nkg/bankofscotland.png">
    <img alt="cancerresearch" class="img-responsive" src="//s3.amazonaws.com/studio4-demofiles/nkg/cancerresearch.png">
    <img alt="bhf-gallery" class="img-responsive" src="//s3.amazonaws.com/studio4-demofiles/nkg/bhf-gallery.png">
    <img alt="Card_Factory" class="img-responsive" src="//s3.amazonaws.com/studio4-demofiles/nkg/Card_Factory.jpg">
    <img alt="superdrug" class="img-responsive" src="//s3.amazonaws.com/studio4-demofiles/nkg/superdrug.png">
    <img alt="Basic CMYK" class="img-responsive" src="//s3.amazonaws.com/studio4-demofiles/nkg/lloyds_pharmacy.jpg">
    <img alt="Ramsdens-Financial-Limited-Logo" class="img-responsive" src="//s3.amazonaws.com/studio4-demofiles/nkg/Ramsdens-Financial-Limited-Logo.gif">
    <img alt="poundstretcher" class="img-responsive" src="//s3.amazonaws.com/studio4-demofiles/nkg/poundstretcher.png">
    <img alt="73e4616e_380x97" class="img-responsive" src="//s3.amazonaws.com/studio4-demofiles/nkg/73e4616e_380x97.png">
  </div>
</div>
```

Any thoughts on how I can get this animation to be smoother?  When using the code above on a page it slows and becomes much more choppy/jumpy.

Any help would be very very much appreciated.

Comment: Please see ["Should questions include “tags” in their titles?"](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/should-questions-include-tags-in-their-titles), where the consensus is "no, they should not"!

Comment: Andreas - please see the second highest answer in your link "Please do not remove key words that happen to be tags when doing so makes the titles muddier."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After a lot more testing and frustration I finally found this site [enter link description here](http://log.vieron.net/articles/pure-css-infinite-scrolling-image-marquee/) and modified my code to look like this:

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
 $(".retailer-scroller .gallery-row img").clone().appendTo( ".retailer-scroller .gallery-row" ); 
});
```

```css
@-webkit-keyframes loop {
  0% {
    -moz-transform: translateX(0);
    -ms-transform: translateX(0);
    -webkit-transform: translateX(0);
    transform: translateX(0);
  }
  100% {
    -moz-transform: translateX(-750%);
    -ms-transform: translateX(-750%);
    -webkit-transform: translateX(-750%);
    transform: translateX(-750%);
  }
}
@-moz-keyframes loop {
  0% {
    -moz-transform: translateX(0);
    -ms-transform: translateX(0);
    -webkit-transform: translateX(0);
    transform: translateX(0);
  }
  100% {
    -moz-transform: translateX(-750%);
    -ms-transform: translateX(-750%);
    -webkit-transform: translateX(-750%);
    transform: translateX(-750%);
  }
}
@-ms-keyframes loop {
  0% {
    -moz-transform: translateX(0);
    -ms-transform: translateX(0);
    -webkit-transform: translateX(0);
    transform: translateX(0);
  }
  100% {
    -moz-transform: translateX(-750%);
    -ms-transform: translateX(-750%);
    -webkit-transform: translateX(-750%);
    transform: translateX(-750%);
  }
}
@keyframes loop {
  0% {
    -moz-transform: translateX(0);
    -ms-transform: translateX(0);
    -webkit-transform: translateX(0);
    transform: translateX(0);
  }
  100% {
    -moz-transform: translateX(-750%);
    -ms-transform: translateX(-750%);
    -webkit-transform: translateX(-750%);
    transform: translateX(-750%);
  }
}
.retailer-scroller {
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  overflow: hidden;
}
.retailer-scroller > .scroller-block {
  position: relative;
  z-index: 1;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  min-width: 100% !important;
  height: 80px;
  -webkit-animation-play-state: running;
  -moz-animation-play-state: running;
  -o-animation-play-state: running;
  animation-play-state: running;
  -moz-transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
  -ms-transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
  -webkit-transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
  transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
  -webkit-animation: loop 160s linear infinite;
  -moz-animation: loop 160s linear infinite;
  -o-animation: loop 160s linear infinite;
  animation: loop 160s linear infinite;
}
.retailer-scroller > .scroller-block > .gallery-row {
  white-space: nowrap;
  float: left;
  display: inline-block;
  overflow: hidden;
  height: 80px;
  min-width: 100%;
}
.retailer-scroller > .scroller-block > .gallery-row img {
    margin: 0 20px;
    max-height: 60px !important;
    width: auto !important;
    display: inline-block;
    filter: url("data:image/svg+xml;utf8,<svg%20xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg'><filter%20id='grayscale'><feColorMatrix%20type='matrix'%20values='0.3333%200.3333%200.3333%200%200%200.3333%200.3333%200.3333%200%200%200.3333%200.3333%200.3333%200%200%200%200%200%201%200'/></filter></svg>#grayscale");
    filter:gray; 
    -webkit-filter:grayscale(100%); 
    -moz-filter: grayscale(100%);
    -o-filter: grayscale(100%);
    filter: grayscale(100%);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="retailer-scroller">
<div class="scroller-block">
<div class="row gallery-row">
<img alt="boots" class="img-responsive" src="//s3.amazonaws.com/studio4-demofiles/nkg/boots.png" >
<img alt="specsavers" class="img-responsive" src="//s3.amazonaws.com/studio4-demofiles/nkg/specsavers.png">
<img alt="RSMcCollLogo" class="img-responsive" src="//s3.amazonaws.com/studio4-demofiles/nkg/RSMcCollLogo.jpg">
<img alt="kirkgate-barbers" class="img-responsive" src="//s3.amazonaws.com/studio4-demofiles/nkg/kirkgate-barbers1.jpg">
<img alt="semichem-red" class="img-responsive" src="//s3.amazonaws.com/studio4-demofiles/nkg/semichem-red.jpg">
<img alt="Poundland-Logo" class="img-responsive" src="//s3.amazonaws.com/studio4-demofiles/nkg/Poundland-Logo.jpg">
<img alt="shoezone" class="img-responsive" src="//s3.amazonaws.com/studio4-demofiles/nkg/shoezone.png">
<img alt="lidl" class="img-responsive" src="//s3.amazonaws.com/studio4-demofiles/nkg/lidl.png">
<img alt="HandT_pawn" class="img-responsive" src="//s3.amazonaws.com/studio4-demofiles/nkg/HandT_pawn-e1427199428773.jpg">
<img alt="store21logo2" class="img-responsive" src="//s3.amazonaws.com/studio4-demofiles/nkg/store21logo2-e1427200645809.jpg">
<img alt="Peacocks-Logo" class="img-responsive" src="//s3.amazonaws.com/studio4-demofiles/nkg/Peacocks-Logo.jpg">
<img alt="optical express" class="img-responsive" src="//s3.amazonaws.com/studio4-demofiles/nkg/optical-express.png">
<img alt="farmfoods" class="img-responsive" src="//s3.amazonaws.com/studio4-demofiles/nkg/farmfoods.png">
<img alt="bankofscotland" class="img-responsive" src="//s3.amazonaws.com/studio4-demofiles/nkg/bankofscotland.png">
<img alt="cancerresearch" class="img-responsive" src="//s3.amazonaws.com/studio4-demofiles/nkg/cancerresearch.png">
<img alt="bhf-gallery" class="img-responsive" src="//s3.amazonaws.com/studio4-demofiles/nkg/bhf-gallery.png">
<img alt="Card_Factory" class="img-responsive" src="//s3.amazonaws.com/studio4-demofiles/nkg/Card_Factory.jpg">
<img alt="superdrug" class="img-responsive" src="//s3.amazonaws.com/studio4-demofiles/nkg/superdrug.png">
<img alt="Basic CMYK" class="img-responsive" src="//s3.amazonaws.com/studio4-demofiles/nkg/lloyds_pharmacy.jpg">
<img alt="Ramsdens-Financial-Limited-Logo" class="img-responsive" src="//s3.amazonaws.com/studio4-demofiles/nkg/Ramsdens-Financial-Limited-Logo.gif">
<img alt="poundstretcher" class="img-responsive" src="//s3.amazonaws.com/studio4-demofiles/nkg/poundstretcher.png">
<img alt="73e4616e_380x97" class="img-responsive" src="//s3.amazonaws.com/studio4-demofiles/nkg/73e4616e_380x97.png">
</div>
</div>
</div>
```

I hope this helps someone else.